# How to send object transform position coordinates over UDP from Unity 3D

Tags: unity, networking, udp

I'm trying to send the x, y and z coordinates of an in-game object over UDP.

I found a script in a Unity forum which should send info over UDP and as I understand it it should send the information from the console. So I created another script to have the x, y and z coordinates to be printed in the console, that script worked but the information wasn't received over UDP.

The networking wasn't an issue, I'd tested the UDP connection by other means and it worked fine.

I then tried to edit the script to send the object coordinates rather than whatever was shown in the console, I tried doing this by editing the line `text = Console.ReadLine()` to say `text = GameObject.Find("Object").transform.position` and linked this to the object but this didn't work. I also changed the `byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)` line to say `byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GameObject.Find("Object").transform.position)` but this didn't work either.

With the help of some more tutorials I then tried creating a new script taking the necessary elements from this script and making it as simple as possible and I couldn't get this to work either, that script would work if what was being sent was just simple text in quotation marks written straight into the script but whatever I tried I couldn't get the coordinates to be sent. And now I am completely out of ideas and have wasted much precious time and would be very grateful if someone could offer any help at all.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class UDPSend : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static int localPort;

    // prefs
    private string IP;  // define in init
    public int port;  // define in init

    // "connection" things
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
    UdpClient client;

    // gui
    string strMessage="";       

    // call it from shell (as program)
    private static void Main()
    {
        UDPSend sendObj=new UDPSend();
        sendObj.init();

        // testing via console
        // sendObj.inputFromConsole();

        // as server sending endless
        sendObj.sendEndless(" endless infos \n");           
    }
    // start from unity3d
    public void Start()
    {
        init();
    }

    // OnGUI
    void OnGUI()
    {
        Rect rectObj=new Rect(40,380,200,400);
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
        GUI.Box(rectObj,"# UDPSend-Data\n127.0.0.1 "+port+" #\n"
                + "shell> nc -lu 127.0.0.1  "+port+" \n"
                ,style);

        // send it
        strMessage=GUI.TextField(new Rect(40,420,140,20),strMessage);
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(190,420,40,20),"send"))
        {
            sendString(strMessage+"\n");
        }      
    }

    // init
    public void init()
    {
        // Define end point , from which the messages are sent.
        print("UDPSend.init()");

        // define
        IP="127.0.0.1";
        port=8050;

        // Send
        remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
        client = new UdpClient();

        // status
        print("Sending to "+IP+" : "+port);
        print("Testing: nc -lu "+IP+" : "+port);
        sendString("jt");
    }

    // inputFromConsole
    private void inputFromConsole()
    {
        try
        {
            string text;
            do
            {
                text = Console.ReadLine();

                // Send the text to the remote client .
                if (text != "")
                {                       
                    // Encode data using the UTF8 encoding to binary format.
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

                    // Send the text to the remote client.
                    client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
                }
            } while (text != "");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            print(err.ToString());
        }           
    }

    // sendData
    private void sendString(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            //if (message != "")
            //{

            // Encode data using the UTF8 encoding to binary format.
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            // Send the message to the remote client.
            client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            print(err.ToString());
        }
    }       

    // endless test
    private void sendEndless(string testStr)
    {
        do
        {
            sendString(testStr);    
        }
        while(true);            
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xyz position isn't likely to be kept as text so what you don't want to do is try to encode it as UTF8. If you don't need to do anything with the coordinates then you should just turn it into a string before encoding, i.e:

```
string pos = GameObject.Find("Object").transform.position.toString();
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pos);
```

Or if you need to manipulate the position on the other end you need to serialize and then deserialise your object position with something [along these lines.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446547/how-to-convert-an-object-to-a-byte-array-in-c-sharp) If that proves to also be a pain to get working because of how the position is actually stored, you should be able to extract each floating point co-ord (x,y, and z) and just turn those into something sendable like:

```
union xyz{
    struct{
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    }
    byte[12] array;
}
```

You'd send xyz.array and on the other side assign it to xyz.array, then access each co-ord via xyz.x, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for sending data over UDP in unity

```
/*
    -----------------------
    UDP-Send
    -----------------------

    // [url]http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb979228.aspx#ID0E3BAC[/url]
*/

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class UDPSend : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static int localPort;

    // prefs
    private string IP;  // define in init
    public int port;  // define in init

    // "connection" things
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
    UdpClient client;

    // gui
    string strMessage="";

    // call it from shell (as program)
    private static void Main()
    {
        UDPSend sendObj=new UDPSend();
        sendObj.init();

        // testing via console
        // sendObj.inputFromConsole();

        // as server sending endless
        sendObj.sendEndless(" endless infos \n");

    }
    // start from unity3d
    public void Start()
    {
        init();
    }

    // OnGUI
    void OnGUI()
    {
        Rect rectObj=new Rect(40,380,200,400);
            GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
                style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
        GUI.Box(rectObj,"# UDPSend-Data\n127.0.0.1 "+port+" #\n"
                    + "shell> nc -lu 127.0.0.1  "+port+" \n"
                ,style);

        // ------------------------
        // send it
        // ------------------------
        strMessage=GUI.TextField(new Rect(40,420,140,20),strMessage);
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(190,420,40,20),"send"))
        {
            sendString(strMessage+"\n");
        }      
    }

    // init
    public void init()
    {
        // Endpunkt definieren, von dem die Nachrichten gesendet werden.
        print("UDPSend.init()");

        // define
        IP="127.0.0.1";
        port=8051;

        // ----------------------------
        // Send
        // ----------------------------
        remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
        client = new UdpClient();

        // status
        print("Sending to "+IP+" : "+port);
        print("Testing: nc -lu "+IP+" : "+port);

    }

    // inputFromConsole
    private void inputFromConsole()
    {
        try
        {
            string text;
            do
            {
                text = Console.ReadLine();

                // Den Text zum Remote-Client senden.
                if (text != "")
                {

                    // Daten mit der UTF8-Kodierung in das Binärformat kodieren.
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

                    // Den Text zum Remote-Client senden.
                    client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
                }
            } while (text != "");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            print(err.ToString());
        }

    }

    // sendData
    private void sendString(string message)
    {
        try
        {
                //if (message != "")
                //{

                    // Daten mit der UTF8-Kodierung in das Binärformat kodieren.
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                    // Den message zum Remote-Client senden.
                    client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
                //}
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            print(err.ToString());
        }
    }


    // endless test
    private void sendEndless(string testStr)
    {
        do
        {
            sendString(testStr);  
        }
        while(true);

    }

}
```